# No shell when connecting to linux server via SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I was connected to a remote server, and after adding some aliases, I ran `source ~/.bash_profile`. The shell froze up, I was disconnected from the server, and now every time I try to log into the server, there is no shell. I can type in the terminal for a few seconds, but I cannot run any commands and after a few seconds, the connection closes.

Comment: you possibly did something wrong - what is the content of `.bash_profile`

Comment: @JaromandaX If I remember correctly, I had
`alias ll="ls -lh"
  alias la="ls -la"
  alias c="clear"`

Comment: Try `ssh -t user@server 'bash --noprofile'`. Does this give you a shell you can use to fix your `~/.bash_profile` on the remote side?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I was able to prevent .bashrc from running by holding ctrl+c as I logged in!

Comment: I've seen symptoms like this where there is an infinite loop in the shell startup files (for example, sourcing ~/.profile from ~/.bash_profile, then sourcing ~/.bash_profile from ~/.profile)

Comment: @mertvy When you add extra information, please edit your post instead of using comments. It put all the information in one place and is more easily searchable.